# Nginx rewrite rule saml

Tags: nginx, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to install simplesaml on nginx web server and I'm running into a problem with the alias, a friend told me to use rewrite and gave me the example below, but his example doesn't work either.

```
rewrite ^/simplesaml/module.php/(.*) /simplesaml/www/module.php?path=$1 last;
            rewrite ^/simplesaml/(.*)$ /simplesaml/www/$1 last;
```

How can I fix this, I'm busting my head since 2 days now,I'm out of ideas.

```
root /home/mihaela/public_html;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been having the same issue and this config is the only one I've found to work.

[Example NGINX config](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simplesamlphp/TvU1qZpWBIs/N6KBsGc-aqgJ)

Here are my nginx configs:

This is my central IDP config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name saml.local;

    root /srv/sites/saml.local/www/;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_URL $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

And here is my config for simplesaml accessible via `/saml`

```
location  /saml {
    alias /srv/sites/site.local/vendor/simplesamlphp/www;
    index index.php;

    location ~ ^(?<prefix>/saml)(?<phpfile>.+?\.php)(?<pathinfo>/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$phpfile;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $pathinfo if_not_empty;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Added my configs into the post